# Align form centered

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On my site I want a `<form>` to center. I've tried everything but still doesn't work. Does it maybe has something to do with that my site is in WordPress?

```
<section id="jobify_widget_search_hero-2" class="widget widget--home widget--home--no-margin widget--home-hero-search">
        <div class="hero-search hero-search--has-overlay hero-search--height-large" style="background-image:url(http://jobboard.jobsbe.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/widget-home-feature-callout-1-2.jpg); ?>; background-position: center center">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="hero-search__content" style="color:#ffffff"><h1 class="hero-search__title" style="color:#ffffff">Vacatures</h1></div>


    <form class="job_search_form job_search_form--flat" action="http://jobboard.jobsbe.be/find-a-job/" method="GET" style="text-align:center" >

        <div class="search_jobs">

            <div class="search_keywords">
                <label for="search_keywords">Keywords</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search_keywords" placeholder="Keywords">
            </div>

            <div class="search_location">
                <label for="search_location">Location</label>
                <input type="text" name="search_location" id="search_location" placeholder="Location">
            </div>

            <div class="search_submit">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </div>
    </form>


        </div>

        </div>

</section>
```

The webpage to few the site is http://jobboard.jobsbe.be/test/

The input boxes and the search boxes need to be centered.

Comment: We can´t help you if we can´t see css or a example for reproduce the error. Please edit a provide us more info.

Comment: I've added the link to the website. I can't put my whole code in here as this is Wordpress made.

Comment: It is really unclear that what exactly isn't in center, and what do you want. Can you please try to make the question better?

Comment: The input boxes and the search boxes need to be centered.

Comment: The input boxes and the search boxes have a float:left, it have to be in display:inline-block;float:inherit, check that and tell us.

Comment: It works Roy, thanks. But the only problem I have now is that the .search_jobs is on multiple pages. I only want it to change on one page.

Answer (score 0):

There is this rule in your `style.css` file:

```
.search_jobs > div, .search_resumes > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Change that to

```
.search_jobs > div, .search_resumes > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then the centering in the parent container will work.

Comment: I've changed it without succes :(

Comment: Indeed to put float:inherit like Roy said. Now its ok :)